# $T : H \to H$ bounded self-adjoint, when is $\sup \langle Tx, x \rangle$ achieved?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T : H \to H$ is a self-adjoint bounded operator, under what conditions can we guarantee that $\sup\limits_{||x|| = 1} \langle Tx, x \rangle \le ||T|| < \infty$ is attained by some $x$?

It's enough that $T$ is compact, but I don't have this condition. I'm looking at $H = L^2([0,1])$ and an operator which isn't compact.

Comment: Write first $T$ as $T_+-T_-$, a difference of two (commuting) operators $T_\pm$ which are $\ge 0$. Then $\|T\|$ is the maximal value among the two norms $\|T_\pm\|$. So we can restrict to the case $T\ge 0$. (If the two norms $\|T_\pm\|$ differ, then take the bigger one, else look for obtaining a maximizing $x$ for either one.) If $T\ge 0$, then by continuous functional calculus, there is an $S\ge 0$ (square root of $T$) with $S^2=T$. Now use $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle S^2x,x\rangle=\langle Sx,Sx\rangle=\|Sx\|^2\le \|S\|^2\;\|x\|^2$. I'd pick an $x$ realizing the equality at the last step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle.$ The value $M$ is attained if and only if $M$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ Indeed assume $$\langle Tx,x\rangle =M,\quad \|x\|=1 $$ The operator $A=MI-T$ is positive and $$\langle Ax,x\rangle =0$$ Hence $Ax=0,$ i.e. $Tx=Mx.$

Comment: Couldn't the sup be less than $||T||$?

Comment: It can be less than $\|T\|.$ I have taken for granted that your question was: when sup is equal $\|T\|.$ The same reasoning is valid if sup is attained and less than $\|T\|.$ I will re-edit.